# how to check if an array object contains an associative array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

Here is an array object that contains an array [body]. How do I get to know that this object has array inside and give me it's keys?

```
Array
(
    [6] => stdClass Object
        (
            [vid] => 6
            [uid] => 1
            [title] => om
            [log] => 
            [status] => 1
            [comment] => 2
            [promote] => 0
            [sticky] => 0
            [nid] => 6
            [type] => article
            [language] => und
            [created] => 1436514497
            [changed] => 1438003101
            [tnid] => 0
            [translate] => 0
            [revision_timestamp] => 1438003101
            [revision_uid] => 1
            [body] => Array
                (
                    [und] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [value]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check whether the object has `body` property, `which is array` and `which should not be empty`.

And fetch the keys it all three conditions fulfill.

Use [is_array(](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php)), [array_keys()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) and [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

```
if (isset($obj->body) && is_array($obj->body) && ! empty($obj->body)) {
  // yes it has
  $keys = array_keys($obj->body);
}
else {
  // either body is not there or body is empty. 
}
```

**EDIT:**

Check if any of the object properties is an array and return its keys.

```
foreach (get_object_vars($obj) as $var) {
  if (gettype($var) == 'array') {
    $keys = array_keys($var);
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to check whether the object has `body` property, instead, I want to check if there is ANY array EXISTS in this object, and if yes, give me its key.

Comment: when I am doing `print_r($keys);die;` outside if condition, it is giving me nothing. It seems like, it always check first value in array i.e. `vid` and it is string not an array, IT IS CHECKING ALL VALUES. I also did `print_r` at the end of foreach loop, this also gives me blank result.

Answer (score 1):

Considering `$main_array` as your given result.
Try this

```
if( is_array($main_array->body) )
{
// do your process
}
```

Comment: I want something like this way.Suppose $compfield is my main array.So `foreach ($compfields as $comp => $comps){foreach ($comps as $value=>$values) {if(is_array($value)){print ($value); } }}` and in `$value`, I want `body`

Answer (score 0):

Check if it is an array with:

http://php.net/manual/de/function.is-array.php

Comment: If you are going to ask the OP to RTM, just post your _hint_ as a comment under the question.  There is not enough effort to educate in this answer.